# using a cursor against Access table from Perl

Tags: sql, perl, ms-access-2010

Perl 5.10
Access 2010

Greetings all,

I've got a table whose key field isn't quite right, defined AUTOINCREMENT but **NOT** PRIMARY KEY. Thus rows with duplicate key values have found their way in to the table.
I need to programattically weed out the duplicate rows, leaving only one row with each
key value, which would then be unique.

Assuming the rows are already in sorted order, something like this should do the job:

```
DECLARE @prevClientId = "XXX";
DECLARE @currClientId = "XXX";
DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR SELECT [Client ID] FROM [Entity Client] FOR UPDATE;
OPEN csr;
FETCH csr INTO @currClientId;
DO {
  IF( @currClientId != @prevClientId) {
      @prevClientId = @currClientId; ) {
  } else {
      DELETE FROM [Entity Client] WHERE CURRENT OF csr;
  }
  FETCH csr INTO @currClientId;
} UNTIL SQLSTATE = '02000';
CLOSE csr;
```

this should step through each row and delete each row whose key value matches the key value of the previous row.

Questions:
1 - Does MS Access allow for cursors?
if Yes, how would one code this up in a perl script?
if No, how else can one step through each row of a table? That's not the same as simply looping through the results of a $sth->fetchrow_arrayref because youre working against the result in memory AFTER all rows have been scanned.

Any other suggestions on how to programatically remove duplicate rows from an Access table would be greatly appreciated.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the duplicates out into a separate table

```
SELECT [Client ID], count(*)  
FROM [Entity Client]
GROUP BY [Client ID]
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY [Client ID]
```

then re-add the rows with with a unique id, finally deleting the duplicated rows